# Query items from a list of groups with certain condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to select certain records from a list.

Here's some sample data

```
declare @datas table(BodyNumber int, Id int, RegNumber bigint, DeletedRegNumber bigint null)
insert into @datas values(70,   355,    559,    559)
insert into @datas values(70,   581,    660,    NULL)
insert into @datas values(53,   424,    354,    354)
insert into @datas values(53,   429,    364,    364)
insert into @datas values(60,   395,    519,    NULL)
insert into @datas values(60,   428,    296,    296)
insert into @datas values(65,   398,    518,    NULL)
insert into @datas values(65,   430,    256,    256)
```

`BodyNumber` can have more than one `RegNumber`. I'm looking for the `Id` where it's not the highest `Id` in the group and the group has a NULL value in the `DeletedRegNumber` column.

For example the first pair (70) is excluded, because the NULL is on "top". The 2nd group (53) is also excluded because there's no NULL in the group. The 3rd and 4th group are important because the NULL values are followed by a non-NULL.

So the query would need to return the rows with `Id` 395 and 398.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm.

```
select d.*
from @datas d
where d.DeletedRegNumber is null and
      exists (select 1
              from @datas d2
              where d2.BodyNumber = d.BodyNumber and d2.id > d.id
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to figure out which row has the lowest id. Use `IN` to only find the body numbers that have a null value.

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT *, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BodyNumber ORDER BY ID ASC) AS rn
FROM @datas)


SELECT *
FROM cte WHERE rn = 1 AND DeletedRegNumber IS NULL
AND bodynumber IN (SELECT bodynumber FROM @datas WHERE DeletedRegNumber IS NULL)
```